# Edit css of standard email page in salesforce

Tags: email, css

- Cases > Activity History > Send an email
- This "send an email" page has fields like

  - To, Additional To, CC, BCC, Subject, Body
- My requirement is I have to hide/ not show BCC on this page.
- I thought if there is way to add a css style on html element which is holding this 'BCC/ Additional To' to `display: none` I can achieve my requirement

My question is: Is there a way to add CSS to standard page as "Send an email" I believe is standard page. Or if there is any other solution, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking for. For this, one would usually use page layouts and not CSS. Otherwise, use a visualforce page and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable [Compliance BCC Emails](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_compliancebcc.htm), and it will automatically disable any user-specified default BCC and remove the field from the Send an Email page.

Comment: SFDCfox,Thanks for your reply, How to remove the field (Like I dont want to show fields like BCC, Additional To completely) from send an email page. I am assuming that it is standard field. Thanks

Comment: The only way to do so is to enable the setting I specified.

Comment: That perfectly worked for BCC SFDCfox. Thanks for that. But my requirement is to hide "Additional to" field as well. Can you please suggest a solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: @pmvsdt sorry. You can't do anything about that.

Comment: One last question, Currently the from field is a picklist with values.. 1) org wide email address (default) 2) user personal email address.. Is there a way for me to display only default email address instead of user (make this field readonly with default address)